# regular expression with If condition question

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expressions that extract everything after first two alphabets

```
^[A-Za-z]{2})(\w+)($) $2
```

now I want to the extract nothing if the data doesn't start with alphabets.

Example:

```
AA123   -> 123
123     -> ""
```

Can this be accomplished by regex?

Comment: Your regex already does that. It matches the input string only if it starts with two letters (`^[A-Za-z]{2}`). If it starts with something else, the regex does not match and there isn't any result captured for the `(\w+)` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an alternative to match any one or more chars from start to end of string if your regex does not match:

```js
^(?:([A-Za-z]{2})(\w+)|.+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v1siju/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a container non-capturing group:

  - `([A-Za-z]{2})(\w+)` - Group 1: two ASCII letters, Group 2: one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (use `[\w\W]+` to match any chars including line break chars)
- `)`  - end of a container non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern already captures 1 or more word characters after matching 2 uppercase chars. The `$` does not have to be in a group, and this  `$2` should not be in the pattern.

```
^[A-Za-z]{2})(\w+)$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X1gZYy/1).

Another option could be a pattern with a conditional, capturing data in group 2 only if group 1 exist.

```
 ^([A-Z]{2})?(?(1)(\w+)|.+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z]{2})?` Capture 2 uppercase chars in optional **group 1**
- `(?` Conditional

  - `(1)(\w+)` If we have group 1, capture 1+ word chars in **group 2**
  - `|` Or
  - `.+` Match the whole line with at least 1 char to not match an empty string
- `)` Close conditional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zhTpmE/1)

For a match only, you could use other variations Using `\K` like [^[A-Za-z]{2}\K\w+$](https://regex101.com/r/vhl5QT/1) or with a lookbehind assertion [(?<=^[A-Za-z]{2})\w+$](https://regex101.com/r/SRwem9/1)